# Pattern match in a column in bash

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I want to grab the rows containing `Subject01`, `Subject02`,...`Subject50` in the text file and separate them in each file. Below is code I did and the result of outputted files are empty. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
Subject01/path/here    4
Subject01/path/here    1
Subject02/path/here    3
Subject03/path/here    5
Subject03/path/here    6
...
```

so one of the output can be in the format below:

```
Subject03/path/here    5
Subject03/path/here    6
```

here is the code I tried and it failed.

```
#!/bin/sh
subject=Subject
for i in {01..50}
do
        awk '{ if ($1 == "${subject}${i}") { print } }' output-0 > output-0-sub-$i
done
```

Comment: I don't understand if you want to simply grep the lines, or save the content of the actual files (`Subject03/path/here`)  in `output-0-sub-$i`. It is probably the second, because if not you can simply `for f in {01..10}; do grep "Subject$f" Input_file >> output-0-sub-$f ;done`

Comment: this `for f in {01..10}; do grep "Subject$f" Input_file >> output-0-sub-$f ;done` worked! but how i can prevent generating empty files? As with this command some outputted files have been generated for example if`Subject04` is not in the first column then its output would be empty. Can this implemented in the script or I have to find some other way

Comment: check the answer

Comment: @user8034918 `grep` returns exit code 1 if no lines where selected. You could either test the exit code, or alternatively test the produced file for emptiness, and delete it if it really is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can simpyl use `grep` for that

```
for f in {01..10}; do
   grep "Subject$f" inputFile.txt >> output-0-sub-$f 
   if [[ ! -s output-0-sub-${f} ]] ; then 
      rm output-0-sub-$f 
   fi
done
```

The if condition is checking if the file is empty and if so, it is deleted.
You could also add the `-f` flag to check if the file exists, but it depends on how your script works.